# How to edit a user in flutter firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have been learning how does flutter work with firestore and now I am working in user auth with password, email and username, when a user is created the email and password are saved with an uid but the username and the email(again) are saved in firestore with a different uid, by the way I have tried a lot of things to make it have the same id but I currently cant find the way. in addition to this, there is also a function that is supposed to edit the username and save those changes. The problem comes when trying to implement the edit functinality because the edit form doesnt return anything as an output except the loading screen, I think this error is happening because of the uids. How can I fix this problem?

models/user.dart

```
class CustomUser {
  final String uid;

  CustomUser({this.uid});
}

class UserData {
  final String uid;
  final String name;

  UserData({this.uid, this.name});
}
```

models/username.dart

```
class Username {
  final String name;

  Username({this.name});
}
```

services/auth.dart

```
class AuthService {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;


  // create user obj based on fb user
  CustomUser _userFromFirebaseUser(User user) {
    return user != null ? CustomUser(uid: user.uid) : null;
  }

  Stream<CustomUser> get user {
    return _auth.authStateChanges().map(_userFromFirebaseUser);
  }

  //signin email password
  Future signInWithEmailAndPassword(String email, String password) async {
    try {
      UserCredential result = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email, password: password);
      User user = result.user;
      return _userFromFirebaseUser(user);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }

  //signup
  Future registerWithEmailAndPassword(String email, String password) async {
    try {
      UserCredential result = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email, password: password);
      User user = result.user;
      return _userFromFirebaseUser(user);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }

  //signout
  Future signOut() async {
    try {
      return await _auth.signOut();
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }
```

services/database.dart

```
class DatabaseService {
  final String uid;
  DatabaseService({this.uid});

  final CollectionReference userCollection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('usernames');

  Future updateUserData(String name) async {  // this is the function that has to edit the username
    return await userCollection.doc(uid).set({
      'name': name,
    });
  }

  Future uploadUserInfo(userMap) async {  // this function adds username and email to firestore
    return await userCollection.doc(uid).set(userMap);
  }

  List<Username> _usernameListFromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
    return snapshot.docs.map((doc) {
      return Username(
        name: doc.data()['name'] ?? '',
      );
    }).toList();
  }

  // userData from snapshot
  UserData _userDataFromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
    return UserData(
      uid: uid,
      name: snapshot.data()['name'],
    );
  }

  Stream<List<Username>> get usernames {
    return userCollection.snapshots().map(_usernameListFromSnapshot);
  }

  Stream<UserData> get userData {
    return userCollection.doc(uid).snapshots().map(_userDataFromSnapshot);
  }
}
```

register.dart(code that registers the user with a username)

```
onPressed: () async {
  if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
    setState(() => loading = true);
    dynamic result = await _auth.registerWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then((val) {
      Map<String, String> userInfoMap = {
        "name": name,
        "email": email,
      };
      databaseService.uploadUserInfo(userInfoMap);
    });
    if (result == null) {
      setState(() {
        error = 'please suply a valid email';
          loading = false;
      });
    }
  }
}),
```

editForm.dart

```
final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
String _currentName;

final user = Provider.of<CustomUser>(context);

StreamBuilder<UserData>(
      stream: DatabaseService(uid: user.uid).userData,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          UserData userData = snapshot.data;
          return Form(
              key: _formKey,
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text('edit username!'),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 30,
                  ),
                  TextFormField(
                    // initialValue: userData.user gives a initial text to the input
                    validator: (val) => val.isEmpty ? 'Please enter a name' : null,
                    onChanged: (val) => setState(() => _currentName = val),
                  ),
                  RaisedButton(
                      child: Text('Save'),
                      onPressed: () async {
                        if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                          print('update if good');
                          await DatabaseService(uid: user.uid).updateUserData(
                            _currentName ?? userData.name,
                          );
                        }
                        Navigator.pop(context);
                      })
                ],
              ));
        } else {
          return Loading();
        }
      },
    );
```

If you have any questions please let me know;)

Comment: add the code for where you initialized `databaseService` in your register.dart? The reason the user actually uid and the firestore id are different stems from that

Comment: You can store the user with it's own uid in firestore. Just retrieve the uid while signup and then do something like this Firestore.instance.collection('users').document(authResult.user.uid).setData({ 'username': username, 'email': email}) , after that you can just add to the user collection using the document id same as the users uid.

Comment: @ByteMe that is what I dont really understand, I have already tried that but I think I did it wrong, can you please explain more on how to do that?

Comment: The uid should be recovered from the firebase register function, but it doesn't seem like you did that. I'll try to answer the question in about 6 hours

Comment: @ByteMe did you found out why is that happening? after thinking about it, saving the username with the same id is not that necesary, the goal is to just edit the username and save those changes, that editForm.dart file calls the user uid and it is not working because username doesnt have the user uid

Comment: where are you getting your `user.uid` in your edit form?

Comment: @ByteMe actually I forgot to add that to my question but I get that from this `final user = Provider.of<CustomUser>(context)` this function is inside the Widget build and before return

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `register.dart`, the `registerWithEmailAndPassword` method returns a `User` object which contains the `uid` internally created by FirebaseAuth however, it doesn't seem like you took used this `uid` to update your `Firestore` user document. I've implemented a sample of what should have been done below.

```dart
dynamic result = await _auth.registerWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then((val) {
  Map<String, String> userInfoMap = {
    "name": name,
    "email": email,
  };
  
  DatabaseService(uid: val.uid).uploadUserInfo(userInfoMap);
});
```

I just realized that your `registerWithEmailAndPassword` function returns a `CustomUser` instead of a Firebase `User`. I just modified it to make it work.

```dart
//signup
  Future<User> registerWithEmailAndPassword(String email, String password) async {
    try {
      UserCredential result = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email, password: password);
      return result.user;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }
```

```dart
//editFrom.dart
//form validation function
Map<String, String> userMap = {'name': currentName}; 
await DatabaseService(uid: user.uid).uploadUserInfo(userMap);
```

Side note: when working with `Futures`, it helps if you specify the expected return type as this will help you with debugging. I've done it for the function above

Comment: This code does save the same uid for the username, email and password but does not edit the username

Comment: hmm, in your editForm.dart, right before you call the `updateUserData` function, could you print the value of the user.uid at that point to ensure that is it not null

Comment: it is null, well I have already fixed that problem by adding a map `Map<String, String> userMap {'name': =currentName}; await DatabaseService(uid: user.uid).uploadUserInfo(
                            userMap,);`, can you add that to your answer so that other people can see it?

Comment: Now the code edits the username and saves it in firestore